# Android Studio is building old version via Generate Signed bundle / APK

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to build APK from `Android studio 3.6.3` to test on the device as well as for publishing app on google play console, but I noticed, Its building APK with the old version, tried almost everything

By the way, the build is working fine on the built-in emulator, however, sometimes it's also building the old version but by removing the build folder it solves the problem.

**build.gradle**

```
// The old version name was 1.1

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.companyName"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

**Versioning**

```
► android: ./gradlew -version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          14.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 14.0.1+7)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

**Tried solutions**

1. File > Invalidate cache/restart > Invalidate cache/restart
2. Build > Clean project
3. Run > Edit Configuration > app > general > before launch > Gradle-aware make

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Search the 'versionName' in your project. Try yo use cmd to build app just like: ./gradlew clean assembleDebug or ./gradlew clean assembleRelease. Use gradle to replace ./gradlew if your machine is windows.

Comment: I am using Mac machine

Comment: Any solution for this issue so far?

Comment: Same happening to me; and always when you just uploaded a botched version to the app store. It is INFURIATING.

Comment: @MuhammadOwais also on a mac

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This happened to me three times now, and on the third I came with a different solution that at least makes sense, so instead of adding another answer, I'll consolidate all answers here; if one sticks in future ocurrences, I'll update the answer again.

#### ATTEMPT #3

Once again it plagued me, but this time I investigated a little more, by `grep`-ing for the old build number after cleaning up, both in the project dir and in `~/gradle`. It turns out the number isn't in the project when you clean, but crops up in the (generated intermediate asset) `BuildConfig.java`, and from there in all places. So my fix was:

- Clean project in Android Studio
- Quit Android Studio
- Ensure no gradle process is running (`ps -Af | grep gradle` should only show the grep, for example)
- Delete the `cache` directory inside `~/.gradle`
- Reopen Android Studio and generate the bundle

#### ATTEMPT #2

So this happened a second time (and this time it wasn't updating even on the devices). Neither of the previous incantations worked, but what did it this time was going to `Edit Configurations...` on the `Run/Debug` dropdown, and switching from "Default APK" to "APK from app bundle".

That seems to have jolted things enough that the devices picked up the new manifest/version.

Hope it works next time!

[image: screenshot of Run/Debug configurations with the dropdown in question]

#### ATTEMPT #1

After trying everything under the sun, I did two things, not sure which one did the trick (strongly suspect the second, will try it in isolation next time)

1. On `Build`, `Select Build Variant...`, I switched from debug to release
2. Built a non-signed bundle (`Build`, `Build Bundle(s)/ APK(s)`, `Build Bundle(s)`).

The built bundle had the new version/manifest. From that point, building a signed bundle worked (suspiciously fast, but I guess it reused the last one and just signed it; app store accepted it as usual, whereas it was rejecting the others for having an already-used build number)

Had to revert "1" to properly debug on devices again (which I did not have to do last time, making me extra inclined to believe just 2 is needed.